# how to change longtext a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2018";s:5:"month";s:2:"07";s:3:"day";s:2:"05";} to date 2018-07-05

Tags: php, date, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi I am using cakephp3 and saving data in key-value pair but not able to convert this

```
a:3:{s:4:"year";s:4:"2018";s:5:"month";s:2:"07";s:3:"day";s:2:"05";}
```

and result i
want in this form

```
date 2018-07-05
```

in php

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanx buddy but why you added negative anyway thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with below

```
$date = unserialize('a:3:s:4:"year";s:4:"2018";s:5:"month";s:2:"07";s:3:"day";s:2:"05";}');

echo 'date '.$date['year'].'-'.$date['month'].'-'.$date['day']; //date 2018-07-05
```